# Constant unnecessary rebuilds when firebase collection is updated including deletion

Tags: flutter

I am currently using the paginate firestore package. Each time something is written to the firebase collection, there is a rebuild of all the visible widgets, and each time a deletion is done, there is a rebuild of all the widgets below the deleted widget.

I tried many things to prevent this, including using unique value keys, using an animatedlist but nothing seems to work so far.

Recently, i added the documentsanapshots[index].id as valuekey to a list of keys in a  list Before doing that, i check to know whether or not that key was already added. If not it that key is added to the widget i want to return, the key is added to the list of keys.

Further down in the code, the widgets are returned from the the list of widgets. How can i correct this? Here's an important snippet of the code: `PaginateFirestore(

```
itemBuilder: (context, documentSnapshots, index) {








        ValueKey docId = ValueKey(documentSnapshots[index].id);

        if (CommentList.commentKeys.contains(docId)) {

        } else {
          CommentList.commentKeys.add(docId);
          CommentList.commentKeys.add(ValueKey(docId));


          CommentList.commentWidgets.add(CommentCard(
            key: docId,
            firstVisibleItemIndex_: 0,
            commenterIndex: index,
            commenterController : controller,
            snap:documentSnapshots[index],
            document: widget.document,
            user: commenters_[index],
            focus: widget.focusNode,


          ));
        }

        return  CommentList.commentWidgets[index];










},
//physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
reverse: false,
scrollController: controller,

// orderBy is compulsory to enable pagination
query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('comments')
    .where('postId', isEqualTo: widget.document['postID'])
//.where('username', isEqualTo: widget.username)
    .orderBy('datePublished', descending: true),
//Change types accordingly
itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
// to fetch real-time data
isLive: true,
itemsPerPage: 4,
initialLoader: const InitialLoader(),//const SingleChildScrollView(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 2,color: Colors.white,))),
onEmpty: const EmptyDisplay(),
```

);`